# Minimizing Windows Console shifts everything up by one line, solution?

Tags: console, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a faithful user to WSL, and I've installed quite some of my favorite Linux softwares like Vim and tmux.

The problems, whenever I minimize the window and restore it, everything gets shifted up by one line, which creates a huge inconvenience to full-screen programs like the two mentioned above.

This is really annoying. Any ideas?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Does it happen only for vim and tmux? And for which distro? Which Windows build?

Comment: @Biswapriyo All full-screen programs including `less`, `apt` (it has a progress bar at the bottom line). Distro irrelevant. Any Windows build starting from Anniversary (14299) (I don't know about preview builds but they should not be exempt).

Comment: You may report the bug to Microsoft. Till fix the only possible solution I believe are third party terminals, like ConEmu.

Comment: @iBug Your issue was filed in GitHub. See this link: https://github.com/microsoft/wsl/issues/742 . You may post in that link.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution:

```
bind-key -n M-r refresh-client
```

Then I hit Alt+R whenever the screen goes wrong.